# Conditionally Pass Data from Enclosing View to Partial View

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

**My Requirement**

I need to render a partial view on selection of a dropdownlist

- On page load (from Controller) I have all the required data(viewmodel) for the Partial View
- All the partial views need to get the same data from the viewmodel of the View(cshtml)
- On selection of the dropdown list value, the required Partial View(given below 1- 4) needs to be rendered.

*Rendering Partial View 1*

```
@{
    Html.RenderPartial("_Dashboard", new Dashboard.Web.Models.SignalDataViewModel { dData = Model.dData });
 }
```

*Rendering Partial View 2*

```
@{
   Html.RenderPartial("_Dashboard_Graph", new Dashboard.Web.Models.SignalDataViewModel { dData = Model.dData });
 }
```

*Rendering Partial View 3*

```
@{
   Html.RenderPartial("_Dashboard_Arrow", new Dashboard.Web.Models.SignalDataViewModel { dData = Model.dData });
}
```

*Rendering Partial View 4*

```
@{
   Html.RenderPartial("_Dashboard_Custom", new Dashboard.Web.Models.SignalDataViewModel { dData = Model.dData });
 }
```

**My Query**

Please suggest how should I conditionally render partial view(from among a list of Partial Views with same ViewModel) as per the selection of dropdown list while having the data for the partial views that's already availble within the View's(cshtml-parent) ViewModel

Comment: Why don't you just stick an onChange onto the dropdown menu and call a javascript function that checks the value passed to it and returns a partialView that way?

Comment: Ok But in java script how should I pass the existing model data(say `dData` mentioned above) to populate the `_partialView` and replace the existing `_partialView`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did some work around to implement this.

In the JavaScript on selection of drop-down, via ajax call I passed the model data to a controller returning Partial View.
In the Controller, the right partial view is decided and it returned back that partial view as html data to my ajax call that I use to be replace within the required(partial view) div.

Answer (score 0):

Inside of doing all of this via html. I would suggest using javascript.

- Have a single div that has an ID such as

  ```
  <div id="InterchangableView"></div>
  ```
- Add an onChange event to the dropdown and pass a javascript function the value of the dropdown
- In the function determine what value it is and call the necessary controller method such as below

  ```
  if(id == 1)
  {
      var json = '{controllerParam: ' + id + '}';

      $.ajax({
          url:'@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")',
          type:'POST',
          data: json,
          contentType:'Application/json',
          success:fucntion(result){
              $("#InterchangableView").html(result);
          }
      });
  }
  ```
- In the controller action, depending on the result passed into it, do a check and return the correct partialView this way.

Every time the dropdown changes, the javascript should get called, which should return a partialView which should overwrite whatever is in the div that that Id is located against.

Comment: When the page is loaded (from the Controller) the page has all the required data to populate the Partial View. Moreover all the partial view gets the same _modeldata - that is from the Model of the Parent View - bcoz all Partial Views displays the same data (value and timeSent) - only the image\widget of the Partial View is different. In this case I would not need to have an ajax call to fetch data. Having the data already within the View's Model how to use jquery to accomplish this?Please suggest.